# Chart that selects cells based on partial data in a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I want to set up a code that will use a cell when a specific portion of data changes... for example:

R01-SP01

R01-SP02

R01-SP03

R01-SP04

R02-SP01

R02-SP02

R02-SP03

R03-SP01

R03-SP02

R03-SP03

R03-SP04

Ideally, the chart would count the first cells (for the x-value) for each increment of "Rxx"

R01-SP01

R02-SP01

R03-SP01

Do I need to write a code for this or is a formula sufficient? If I end up using a formula, do I need to make a new table, and if so, how can I hide the table without it affecting the chart?

Comment: What do you mean? You want to count how many cells have `R01`, then how many have `R02`, etc? What about `COUNTIF()`? What have you tried?

Comment: I am working on a chart that will display a new column for each instance that "Rxx" goes up an interval. As it stands, I have a chart that displays all of the data, but I want to have an additional table that condenses the data to just the "Rxx" increments. I have been trying to work on a table that runs off of an array/index formula. The problem comes with the fact that if I hide the cells, the chart will not display. I don't want to flood the workbook with redundant tables.